# which annotation field call the method

Tags: java, annotations

I have custom annotation class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface Range {

        int min();
        int max();
 }
```

I have another class which has a lot of field and I want to use annotation in order to check the value of the field whether it is in the range.

```
public class AsdFile {

@Range(min = 0, max = 59)
private int sec;
@Range(min = 0, max = 59)
private int minsec;
@Range(min = 0, max = 24)
private int hour;
@Range(min = 1, max = 31)
private int day;
```

And i want to write a method in this class which controls the range like that

```
public void validateRange(int input) 
{
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for(Field field: fields)
    {

        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Range.class))

        {

            Range range = field.getAnnotation(Range.class);
            int max = range.max();
            int min = range.min();
            if ( ( input <= max ) && (input >= min) )
            {
                System.out.println("Value in range");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Value is not in range");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I want to control the value for the specific annotation but I dont know how to do that

Comment: It seems your code is fine. what is error?

Comment: It checks the range for all annotated fields like that

Comment: second: 34
max: 59min: 0
Value in range
max: 59min: 0
Value in range
max: 24min: 0
Not in range
max: 31min: 1
Not in range
max: 12min: 1
Not in range but i want to control just for second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to validation on particular field.  your code  will do validation on four field.

This might help you if I understand your question correctly. i.e.

Pass paramter of field name in method:

```
asdFile.validateRange("sec",10);
```

Check a validation after checking field name:

```
public void validateRange(String fieldname, int input) 
    {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for(Field field: fields)
        {

            if(field.getName().equals(fieldname)){
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Range.class))

            {

                Range range = field.getAnnotation(Range.class);
                int max = range.max();
                int min = range.min();
                if ( ( input <= max ) && (input >= min) )
                {
                    System.out.println("Value in range");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Value is not in range");
                }

            }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will do validation on "sec" field only.

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i want. but this situation violates private access modifier. am i right

Comment: yes right if you are trying to access it in other class.